# VBox Guest Additions не подтягивают нужное разрешение экрана (только 800х600) (Debian 10.x, amd64)

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox

Почитал ранее за эту проблему. Не нашёл решения, по этому решил отписать сюда. Использовал много разнообразных методов, как пример: [отсюда](https://superuser.com/questions/950431/how-to-install-virtual-box-guest-additions-on-debian)

У меня ОС Debian 10. Выставил значение RAM: 1536 МБ, а VRAM: 128 МБ в самом VBox-e. Проблема заключается в том что после того как я подключил образ гостевого дополнения и смонтировал его в media/cdrom, и скрипт ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run все прошло просто прекрасно, никаких ошибок не было, но после ребута системы, разрешение изменить невозможно, а само оно не подтягивается как нужно. У меня стоит **базовая сборка**, без GUI. Вот перечень команд:

```
# su

-- Ввод пароля --

# cd /
# apt update ; apt upgrade 
# apt install build-essential dkms
# mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom && cd /media/cdrom
# sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
# apt install virtualbox-guest-utils
# reboot
```

К сожалению после ребута как было сказано выше ничего не помогло. Хотя на других ОС (в видео, и статьях) вполне так неплохо работало. Подскажите, в чем моя ошибка? Возможно я что-то упустил, а то работать в 800х600 не очень удобно :)

Comment: https://www.vmware.com/ru/products/workstation-player.html

Comment: @PavelGridin, спасибо за VMware, я знаю про него. Но я хочу узнать в чем причина именно с VBox, я же не спрашиваю как выбрать клиент виртуалочки? Просто хочу разобраться в чем фигня, почему у остальных работает, а у меня нет, и в чем может быть соль.

Comment: ну я подозреваю, что из-за hyper-v, я ответил в другом вопросе

Comment: @PavelGridin, да. Все переплетено. Но явно не разрешение экрана, херня какая-то, как гостевые дополнения связанны с хайпер-ви? Это блин просто хрень которая модифицирует вибокс, и только. Но ладно, если не решу этот вопрос, то просто буду сидеть с VMware, уже работает нормально.